# Why do I get HEX2BIN() error for long (but valid) strings?

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function

In Excel 2010, the formula `=hex2bin("111",10)` gives the right answer of `0100010001`. According to the [function help](http://excelfunctions.net/Excel-Hex2Bin-Function.html), the arguments should be at most 40 bits (10 hex digits). However, the following versions give me a `#NUM!` error:

```
=hex2bin("200",10)
=hex2bin("100",11)
```

i get similar (mis)behaviour when using the `bin2hex()` function.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: you say "long [...] strings" in your title. "200" is not long by most people's estimation. Are these the exact hex numbers that give you the error? `#num!` will get thrown if the "places" integer parameter specifies a size too small to fit the binary conversion.

Comment: @horatio - "long" is a relative qualifier. 10 bits are enough to represent 0x200. 11 bits are more than necessary to represent 0x100 (0x111 is OK with 10 bits). Then, the help mentions 40 bits limit.

Comment: FYI, the help page you identified is not the official help page. You can access official help articles from within Excel (access from the Insert Function dialog or press F1 and search) or online [here](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/).

Comment: @Excellll - the funny thing is that I got to that page via the Excel help window (F1)... searching for that function gave a list of links and this was one of the first ones.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The maximum valid input to **HEX2BIN()** is **1FF**

From [Excel HEX2BIN function help](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/hex2bin-HP005209110.aspx):

> If number is negative, it cannot be less than FFFFFFFE00, and if
>   number is positive, it cannot be greater than 1FF.

Comment: Any reference?? This looks as the de-facto max, but not according to the help.

Comment: I added the reference for you.

Comment: @Excellll  Thank you very much! .........I checked **MSDN** for "official" documentation on the limits, but I was not successful.

Comment: @Excellll - Great find, thanks. This solves the mystery.